# JavaScript wouldn't reset onclick property on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors web app. When the player chooses Rock Paper or Scissors, it forbids him to choose again until he hits reset button. However the Reset button won't change the onclick properties back.

Here's the code I use. In HTML the "rock", "paper" and "scissors" buttons are made via button tag, not input with type of button. What did I do wrong?

```
function getPlayerChoice(choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 'rock':
            document.getElementById("rock").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("paper").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("scissors").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("humanchoice").src = "pics/rock.png";
            break;
        case 'paper':
            document.getElementById("rock").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("paper").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("scissors").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("humanchoice").src = "pics/paper.png";
            break;
        case 'scissors':
            document.getElementById("rock").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("paper").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("scissors").onclick = "nill";
            document.getElementById("humanchoice").src = "pics/scissors.png";
            break;
    }
};

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("rock").onclick = "getPlayerChoice('rock')";
    document.getElementById("paper").onclick = "getPlayerChoice('paper)";
    document.getElementById("scissors").onclick = "getPlayerChoice('scissors')";
    document.getElementById("humanchoice").src = "pics/favicon.png";   
}
```

HTML code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pics/favicon.png">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Rock Paper Scissors</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="score">
        <p class="score">
            0:0
        </p>
        <p class="result">
            You may start now.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="field">
        <div id="computer-choice">
            <img id="humanchoice" src="pics/favicon.png">
        </div>
        <div id="player-choice">
            <img id="compchoice" src="pics/favicon.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="choice">
        <p>Make your choice</p>
        <div id="choices">
            <button class="button" onclick="getPlayerChoice('rock')" id="rock">
                <img src="pics/rock.png">
            </button>
            <button class="button" onclick="getPlayerChoice('paper')" id="paper">
                <img src="pics/paper.png">
            </button>
            <button class="button" onclick="getPlayerChoice('scissors')" id="scissors">
                <img src="pics/scissors.png">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">reset</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `onclick` property expects to be assigned a function, not a string of JS to eval. (There must be a duplicate around here somewhere… goes hunting)

Comment: `document.getElementById("humanchoice").src = "pics/favicon.png";` this line is wrong

Comment: also `nill` is not `null`, your assigning things which should functions as strings

Comment: Coudn't find anything similar :(

Comment: Just make the button disable instead of removing the function from `onclick`. Otherwise, you use `addEventListner` to add the function event and `removeEventListner` to remove the function event.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks a lot, Soumen and Quentin!